# EMQX behind Nginx ssl proxy

Tags: mqtt, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy, emqx

I have a cluster of three EMQX nodes. Nginx is used as a load balancer. The problem is I **can** connect the load balancer using WSS protocol and get MQTT topics, however, **can't** connect the cluster with MQTT.

I read this article https://www.emqx.io/docs/en/v5.0/deploy/cluster/lb.html#configure-haproxy-nginx-in-emqx and created stream section in my nginx.conf as it was described in the article. My Nginx is built with `stream_ssl_module`. Config looks like given below:

```
stream {
    log_format basic '$proxy_protocol_addr - $remote_addr [$time_local] '
                     '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                     '$session_time';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  basic;

    upstream emqx-tcp {
        zone tcp_servers 64k;
        hash $remote_addr;
        server emqx-01.node-01:1883;
        server emqx-02.node-02:1883;
        server emqx-03.node-03:1883;
    }

    server {
        listen 8883 ssl;
        #status_zone tcp_server;

        proxy_pass emqx-tcp;
        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        ssl_handshake_timeout 10s;

        ssl_certificate /certs/domain.name.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /certs/domain.name.key;
    }
}
```

In emqx.conf on every EMQX node I have section for tcp listener:

```
listeners.tcp.default {
    bind = "0.0.0.0:1883"
    proxy_protocol = true
}
```

When I'm trying to connect mqtt, I get following records in nginx/access.log:

```
- - my.ip.addr.ess [10/Jul/2023:13:49:10 +0000] TCP 200 0 79 3.428
- - my.ip.addr.ess [10/Jul/2023:13:49:15 +0000] TCP 200 0 79 3.435
- - my.ip.addr.ess [10/Jul/2023:13:50:01 +0000] TCP 200 0 79 3.478
- - my.ip.addr.ess [10/Jul/2023:13:50:07 +0000] TCP 200 0 79 3.424
```

And while I'm getting this records, in my MQTT client (MQTT Explorer app) I'm receiving message "Disconnected from server".

**UPD:**
Here is HTTP proxy config, which is used for WSS connections and works fine:

```
upstream emqx-ws {
    least_conn;
    server emqx-01.node-01:8083 weight=1;
    server emqx-02.node-02:8083 weight=1;
    server emqx-03.node-03:8083 weight=1;
}

server {
    listen 9022 ssl;
    server_name     domain.name;

    ssl_certificate /certs/domain.name.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /certs/domain.name.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr:$remote_port;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        proxy_pass http://emqx-ws/mqtt;
    }
}
```

I've read everything I could find covering this topic but couldn't make this work.

Comment: Just to be clear here, the configuration for MQTT over Secure WebSockets (wss://) is not shown here, and all of that is using normal HTTP proxying on a different port?

Comment: I've just added config for WSS proxy into the question. Ports used for MQTT and WSS differ.

Comment: @RodionBaskakov:
Hello , I am trying to create single node emqx cluster and use nginx reverse proxy on it , on my custom domain emqx.test.co
I am able to access emqx dashboard , but I not able to connect to websocket client from dashboard using wss or ws . Can you please let me know what exact configuration you used for nginx and emqx as you mentioned you are able to connect to mqtt over wss?

Comment: @RodionBaskakov: 
Getting below error: 
WebSocket connection to 'wss://emqx.example.co:8084/mqtt' failed: 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://emqx.example.co/#/websocket' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://emqx.example.co:8083/mqtt'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

Comment: My question was not about connecting MQTT over WS(S), I asked about creating a TCP connection to EMQX-cluster behind Nginx proxy.